# slow loading div dead space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that has a custom google map within it; it takes a bit longer to load then the rest of the page. So, currently before it completely loads it creates deadspace, so the elements below it, load as if the div with the google map isn't there -- until the div with the google map loads then it pushes down the elements under it into correct position. It looks pretty bad on page load.

Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this?

I tried defining the diminsions within the CSS.

```
#gmp  {
    background-color: #E5E3DF;
    height: 300px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}


$("#gmp").css("display","block").css("position","absolute")
```

Also tried defining dimensions inline too.

Comment: is #gmp the container div of the google map as i suppose it is?

Comment: try adding `min-height` and `min-width` css properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah you can use a fixed "area" for the google map you're trying to load in, then you could choose to "onLoad" make an ajax call to load our map into the div of your choice.

If have jquery available you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gmp').load('http://google.com/loadmymap', function() {
       alert('Load was performed.');
    });
});
```

check here 
http://api.jquery.com/load/

oh and don't make it absolute ie don't do:
$("#gmp").css("display","block").css("position","absolute")
but just display:block in the original css

Comment: Or I could nest it within a Div with defined height and width. This worked perfectly; but your answer is probably the best route.

Comment: you could do that, it makes no real difference, and glad to be of help!